# python matplotlib animation save error when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, python-multiprocessing

I'm creating a matplotlib animation that runs through a sequence of images from file.  The files that I'm visualizing are typically quite large and there is a significant load time (~5sec) for each stack of images.  I've managed to get the animation to run smoothly by staggering the loading processes with multiprocessing, but I'm having trouble saving the animation as a video file.

Here's the code:

```
from matplotlib import animation
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging
logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)
import time

def qloader(queue, threshold=100, nfiles=3):
    '''trigger a load process if number of items in queue drops below threshold'''
    while nfiles:
        if queue.qsize() < threshold:
            logger.info( 'qsize {}'.format(queue.qsize()) )

            time.sleep( 1 )     #pretend to load data
            data = np.random.rand(25,100,100)

            logger.info( 'Adding data to queue' )
            for d in data:
                queue.put(d)
            logger.info( 'Done adding data!' )
            nfiles -= 1
    else:
        queue.put( None )        #sentinal

def update(frame, im, queue):
    '''update the image'''
    logger.info( 'Updating frame %d'%frame )
    data = queue.get()
    if data is None:
        print( 'Queue is empty!' )
        return

    im.set_data( data )
    return im


#create data queue
mgr = mp.Manager()
queue = mgr.Queue()
threshold = 20          #

#start load process
p = mp.Process( name='loader', target=qloader, args=(queue, threshold) )
p.start()

#start animation
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow( np.random.rand(100,100) )
ani = animation.FuncAnimation( fig, update, frames=75, interval=100, repeat=0, fargs=(im, queue) )
ani.save('foo.mp4', 'ffmpeg')
```

The code runs without errors, but the file it produces is somehow corrupted.  When I try view it with vlc I get a long repeating error stream...

```
$ vlc foo.mp4 
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0xf69108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x7f37fcc01ac8] mp4 demux error: cannot find any /moov/trak
[0x7f37fcc01ac8] es demux error: cannot peek
...
[0x7f37fcc01ac8] ps demux error: cannot peek
[0x7f37fcc01ac8] mpgv demux error: cannot peek
[0x7f37fcc01ac8] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
[0x7f37fcc01ac8] ps demux error: cannot peek
[0x7f3824000b78] main input error: no suitable demux module for `file/://.../foo.mp4'
...
```

I've tried saving in various file formats, using various writers and encoders, with much the same result.

This problem only occurs when using `multiprocessing` to load the data.  If I just create the data with `data = np.random.rand(75,100,100)`, the animation saves without problems.

**Question:**  How do I get `matplotlib.animation` to play along with `multiprocessing`?

Comment: try returning `im` even if the queue is empty.

Comment: Tried. Failed.  As far as I can tell the `vlc` demux error indicates missing data.  The output file is only a few bytes in size, so I think none of the frames are actually being written to disc.

Comment: In the process of trying to debug this.  By setting `rc('verbose', level='debug-annoying', fileo=sys.stdout)` I'm getting this output: `MovieWriter -- Command stdout:
''
MovieWriter -- Command stderr:
'Stream mapping:\n  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0\nPress ctrl-c to stop encoding\nframe=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    \r\nvideo:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 647.368421%`

Comment: I suspect you need a join on your multi processing.

Comment: You may be right, but for some reason `queue.join()` stalls the program indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

By default `animation.MovieWriter` uses a `subprocess.PIPE` to feed the frames to the writer.  This does not seem to work when using `multiprocessing` for some reason.  Changing the last line to 
    `ani.save('foo.mp4', 'ffmpeg_file')`
tells the writer to temporarily save the frames to disc before composing the movie, which side-steps the problem.